# jquerymobile attibute data-role="button" no working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to add or remove jquerymobile attribute `data-role="button"` from anchor tag on window resize means something like:

```
  <a href=".." class="mobilebutton">Hello</a>

  if(windowsize < 700)
    $(".mobilebutton").attr("data-role", "button");
  else 
    $(".mobilebutton").removeAttr("data-role");
```

But its not working may be because page is already created so adding `data-role` attribute have no effect because `jquerymobile.js` have no knowledge about this attribute which we added.
Can anyone tell me workaround for this?

Comment: This is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10578545/1226698 . I gave an example that should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your logic in the [pagecreate](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) event which will fire before jQueryMobile enhances the markup.

Comment: thanks for answer but i mentioned already in the ques that "the page is already created" we are just resizing the window

Answer (score 0):

When the page is already created (so the markup was enhanced), you can't revert the enhancement by removing the attribute.

A button markup of:

```
<a id="myButton" href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a>
```

Will look like this after enhancement:

```
<a id="myButton" href="index.html" data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Link button</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

So one way to get rid of the enhanced markup is to replace it with the pre-enhanced markup manually:

```
$("#myButton").replaceWith('<a id="myButton" href="index.html">Link button</a>');
```